# Derivative of a 1D function involving matrix inversion

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

How do I compute the derivative of
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\mathbf{a} - x \mathbf{b}\right)^T (x \mathbf{A} + \mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \left(\mathbf{a} - x \mathbf{b}\right),
$$
where $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are column vectors, $\mathbf{A}$ is a square symmetric matrix, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix, and $\mu > 0$? Of course, we assume that $x$ is in the interior of the domain where the inverse is well-defined. If possible, I'd like to find a formula which avoids the need to compute the Eigendecomposition of $\mathbf{A}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
g &= {xb-a} &\qiq dg = b\;dx \\
H &= {xA + \mu I} &\qiq dH = A\;dx \\
K &= H^{-1} &\qiq dK = -K\,dH\,K \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function.
Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \frac{1}{2}\BR{g^TKg} \\
\\
df &= \frac{1}{2}\BR{dg^TKg\;+\;g^T\,dK\,g\;+\;g^TKdg} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\BR{b^TKg\;-\;g^TKAKg\;+\;g^TKb}\,dx \\
\\
\grad{f}{x} &= \frac{1}{2}\BR{b^TKg\;-\;g^TKAKg\;+\;g^TKb} \\
}$$

Comment: Since $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, so does $\mathbf{K}$. Introducing $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{Kg}$, you end up with the nice gradient expression $\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{b}-\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{z}$.